# Shortcut method to find atomic term symbols ignoring the spin orbit coupling

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, electronic-configuration, spin

Is there any shortcut method by which we can find the atomic term symbols ignoring the spin-orbit coupling, i.e. ignoring the values of J.

For instance, when writing the d-d transitions for any complex, we write the atomic term symbols and them split them further into other states. I know the lengthy procedure to find the term symbols by considering the values of Ml, and finding the exact states including the spin-orbit coupling but is there a shortcut way by which we may find the atomic term symbols?
[image: Correlation diagram for d2 configuration]

Like, in the above picture, how did we find the terms for d<sup>2</sup> to be <sup>1</sup>S, <sup>1</sup>G, <sup>3</sup>P, <sup>1</sup>D, and <sup>3</sup>F

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on the internet, and going through textbooks, I understand there is no "shortcut-method" to get the atomic term symbols in atoms with a large number of electrons.